# Batch File to change registry value

Tags: batch-file, cmd, registry

I've got a batch file to search for a serial device but since this needs to be executed on multiple servers, I need to dynamically obtain the correct path.
This is fine until I get to a key which contains a space which then breaks the variable that the path is set to.

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\FTDIBUS\<Hardware IDs>\0000\Device Parameters"
```

The issue is the HKEY....\0000 is stored as a variable called %output%.

How can I create a new variable which contains the \Device Parameters key, or concatenate this to the existing variable?

Answer (score 0):

Just found out you can concatenate two variables using

```
%variable1%%variable2%.
```

Solved the issue I was having